# Hosting an interactive web service in a windows form application

Tags: c#, windows, wcf, forms

So I know how to host an WCF service in a windows form application.
But How do I get the service to interact with the controls on the form.
For example I want the web service call to load an image into a picture control.  Please let me know if you found a way to do this.

Comment: You need to get the code execution back onto the UI thread. Some of the IDesign samples demonstarte this.

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do this is like below...

*NOTE: I would be a bit worried about this approach and would probably want to know more about what you want to achieve before doing something like this but in the interests of answering your question here it is...*

Let's say you want to allow someone to send you a picture to display in a picture box on a form so starting from the service, it could look like this:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IPictureService
{
    [OperationContract]
    void ShowPicture(byte[] picture);
}

[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)] 
public class PictureService : IPictureService
{
    private readonly Action<Image> _showPicture;

    public PictureService(Action<Image> showPicture)
    {
        _showPicture = showPicture;
    }

    public void ShowPicture(byte[] picture)
    {
        using(var ms = new MemoryStream(picture))
        {
            _showPicture(Image.FromStream(ms));    
        }            
    }
}
```

Now create a form that you will use to display the picture (Form1 is the name of the form and pictureBox1 is the picture box in question).  The code for that would look like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private readonly ServiceHost _serviceHost;

    public Form1()
    {
        // Construct the service host using a singleton instance of the
        // PictureService service, passing in a delegate that points to
        // the ShowPicture method defined below
        _serviceHost = new ServiceHost(new PictureService(ShowPicture));
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // Display the given picture on the form
    internal void ShowPicture(Image picture)
    {
        Invoke(((ThreadStart) (() =>
                                   {
                                       // This code runs on the UI thread
                                       // by virtue of using Invoke
                                       pictureBox1.Image = picture;
                                   })));
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Open the WCF service when the form loads
        _serviceHost.Open();
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        // Close the WCF service when the form closes
        _serviceHost.Close();
    }
}
```

for completeness, add an app.config and put in this (obviously haw you host the service does not really matter as WCF will abstract it away to a large extent but I wanted to give you a fully working example):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
        <service name="WindowsFormsApplication1.PictureService">
            <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="WindowsFormsApplication1.IPictureService">
                <identity>
                    <dns value="localhost" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
            <host>
                <baseAddresses>
                    <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8732/WindowsFormsApplication1/PictureService/" />
                </baseAddresses>
            </host>
        </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

And that is it - if you send the ShowPicture operation a byte array that is an image, it will be displayed on the form.

For example say create a console application and add a service reference to the service hosted in the winforms application defined above, the main method could simply have this in it (and the logo.png will get displayed on the form):

```
var buffer = new byte[1024];
var bytes = new byte[0];
using(var s = File.OpenRead(@"C:\logo.png"))
{
    int read;
    while((read = s.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
        var newBytes = new byte[bytes.Length + read];
        Array.Copy(bytes, newBytes, bytes.Length);
        Array.Copy(buffer, 0, newBytes, bytes.Length, read);
        bytes = newBytes;
    }              
}

var c = new PictureServiceClient();
c.ShowPicture(bytes);
```